# first loop use as an Infinite loop

Tags: c++

why first loop use as an infinite loop?
Here `int t` is always a positive number.The value of `z` is increasing each iteration and after that, it will be equal to the t and the loop will terminate.But in the run-time, the loop used as an infinite loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int t;  /// t always a positive number
    scanf("%d",&t);
    int z=0;
    while(z!=t) ///first loop
    {
        string s;
        int r,n;
        cin>>s>>r>>n;
        int l=0,i,j,k=0;
        while(s[l]!='\0')
            l++;
        for(i=0;i<r;i++)
        {
            l=l*2;
            char a[l];
            for(j=0;j<l/2;j++)
            {
                if(s[j]=='1')
                {
                    a[k]='1';
                    a[k+1]='0';
                }
                else
                {
                    a[k]='0';
                    a[k+1]='1';
                }
                k+=2;
            }
            int m=0;
            while (a[m]!='\0')
            {
                s[m]=a[m];
                m++;
            }

        }
        cout<<s[n]<<endl;
        z++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think the marked look is infinite?

Comment: Please create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for this. How do you even sure the first cycle is infinite, not some of the nested cycles?

Comment: Where is t defined?
Because if t is not set, it can't be like z for any number.

Comment: This loop can be avoided if scanning `0` into t. Why do you think t is always positive?

Comment: Could not reproduce. You should use the debugger to step through the code and inspect the values.

Comment: SO should come up with a "student's homework" section. These questions don't add any value to the community.

Comment: @logout maybe a "forum" section, whose posts could be upgraded into Q&As once solved or thrown away automatically? Sounds interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is, the infinite loop might not be the outer one `while(z!=t)`, but the inner

```
while (a[m]!='\0')
{
    s[m]=a[m];
    m++;
}
```

because you check for a NUL character, but never set any `a[]` char to `\0`.

So you might have a buffer overrun, which will eventually result in a core dump.

Comment: Yep, and char a[l]; should be char a[l+1] = "\0"; to work